# What is the I2C address of a sensor?

Tags: i2c

I have connected BMP180 sensor:

[image]

to Arduino and was able to read its values with appropriate samples (from [`Adafruit BMP085 Library`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-BMP085-Library) and [`Adafruit BMP085 Unified`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP085_Unified)).

Apparently, this sensor is sending information via [I2C bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C).

However, I2C protocol assumes addresses of connected devices.

What are addresses in my case? How to know and/or change them?

Is it possible to connect several BMP180 to a single Arduino?

Comment: Datasheet. Library source. Why think anywhere else?

Comment: It was hard to believe for me, that address is burned into IC once forever.

Comment: It isn't "burned", it's just part of the logic of the IC.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand, what is the reason to have addressing system without an ability to assign addresses. It is somehow normal to have fixed MAC addresses, because they are long and can be done globally unique, but what is the reason to have fixed 8 bit addresses? There is a big chance that different devices will have same address and impossible to use together.

Comment: http://www.nxp.com/technicalsupport/

Comment: So, you don't know a reason?

Comment: I have yet to run into a conflict that causes me problems.

Comment: This just means that you were using much less than 256 device types in your life :)

Comment: Why would I want to use that many devices on a bus as slow as I2C?

Comment: You don't need to use 256 devices at once. You just need to meet collision once, for any of two devices. Since there are 256 addresses at all, hence you need to use 256 TYPES of devices in your life and you will meet a collision.

Comment: It's one of the features of the I2C protocol. The devices have a known address. And yes, if you have more than 256 devices you are going to have problems. From the datasheet: `A pin compatible product 
variant with SPI interface is possible upon customer’s request` - but even SPI has issues. Look up I2C on Wikipedia - it is a nice idea but runs into problems once lots of people start using it. These are small and cheap devices. For a couple of dollars you could interface each one to an ATtiny processor. Then devise your own way of handling collisions in information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> **4.2 Device and register address**
>
> The BMP085 module address is shown below. The LSB of the device address distinguishes between read (1) and write (0) operation, corresponding to address 0xEF (read) and 0xEE (write).

With the Wire library you divide that by 2 (because it handles the read/write bit) so the address for using with Wire is:

```C++
0xEE / 2 = 0x77
```

Which is mentioned in the Adafruit library:

```C++
#define BMP085_I2CADDR 0x77
```

> Is it possible to connect several BMP180 to a single Arduio?

You can certainly connect **two** of them. From the datasheet:

> There is an easy way to connect two BMP085 to the same I2C bus: You can use the XCLR input of BMP085 to set one BMP085 part silent while you communicate with the other BMP085 part via I2C and vice versa. The signals can be provided by two digital outputs of the microcontroller, or one digital output and one inverter.

If you have access to the XCLR input (the Adafruit board broke it out, I can't tell with the board in your photo) you could use that method. Otherwise do what some of the other answers suggested, and use an I2C multiplexer.

Comment: So, address is embedded into hardware and it is impossible to change it? I have read that `BMP180` does not have `XCLR` input, so I can't connect even two of them is this is true?

Comment: What is the reason to embed several bits without any ability to change them? Isn't it normal to expect several sensors connected to single controller or this is bad practice?

Comment: There is a conflict here between trying to make cheap, simple devices, and having someone wanting to have 1000 of them in some sort of network. Some I2C devices have pins you can tie high or low to alter their addresses. This particular one, being small, does not seem to have that ability.

Comment: May be I still don't understand something. Why are you speaking about network of 1000 devices? From my point of view I require only 2 devices and bad luck. Suppose I bought device 1 and device 2 and accidentally they have same address which I can't change. I need to throw one of devices into trash can and order a new one, still having a big chance it will have same address again.

Comment: They won't *accidentally* have the same address. They will have the same address *by design*.

Comment: Look, say you bought 20 DVD players. They all have the same remote control. The remote control affects all of them at the same time because they have the same *address*. This is by design, not some sort of fault.

Comment: You bought these sensors for around $1 on eBay. What do you expect for that price?

Comment: This is what my point is. DVD players are not intended to be selectable by address. Usually one buy one player and use it in one room. If somebody buy 20 players and wish to use them in one big hall, his usage will be UNEXPECTED. This is opposite for devices with I2C (as I see it). An addressing is EXPECTED usage.

Comment: So, you mean, that more expensive sensors WILL have some option to select address, like jumpers or something, as you said?

Comment: Either connect the second one to separate pins, and use software (bitbanged) I2C. Or use some method of multiplexing I2C devices, like for example [explained here](http://hackaday.com/2015/07/27/i2c-hacks-how-to-splice-clocks-into-chip-selects/)

Comment: `So, you mean, that more expensive sensors WILL have some option to select address` - I cannot speak for every sensor ever made, however I know that the I2C port expanders have three jumpers, hence you can adjust them to have 8 addresses (2 * 2 * 2 addresses).

Comment: See [4 Channel I²C Multiplexer](http://dsscircuits.com/sale/product/dssc0107) - for $US 6.50 you could connect up 4 I²C devices with the same address. Also see [I2C - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C#Limitations) - there they state *The assignment of slave addresses is one weakness of I²C. Seven bits is too few to prevent address collisions between the many thousands of available devices, and manufacturers rarely dedicate enough pins to configure the full slave address used on a given board.* It's an acknowledged problem.

Answer (score 1):

Line 30 in [Adafruit_BMP085.h](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-BMP085-Library/blob/master/Adafruit_BMP085.h) clearly give you the address of sensor. Looks like the address is fixed meaning the only way you can connect several of these sensors is using a i2c multiplexer